# Function cannot be referenced

Tags: c++

I'm encountering an error while trying to add a `Student` object to a `StudentDatabase` structure in C++. The `StudentDatabase` structure contains an array of `Student` objects, and I'm using a function `addStudent` to add a new student to the database. However, I'm getting the following error:

> function "Student::operator=(const Student &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

I've checked the `Student` struct, and I don't see any explicit deletion of the assignment operator. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```cpp
enum class Major
{
    //...,
    Undefined
};

struct Student {
    const char Name[STUDENT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = "";
    unsigned Fn = 0;
    Major Major = Major::Undefined;
};

struct StudentDatabase {
    unsigned StudentsCount = 0;
    Student Students[MAX_STUDENTS_COUNT];
};

void addStudent(StudentDatabase& db, Student s) {
    //if the student does not exist, add them to the "db"
    db.Students[db.StudentsCount++] = s;
}

int main() {
    // Code to add students to the database
    return 0;
}
```

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks look one (or more) of the members in the `Student` structure is invalidating the assignment operator. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT, I think I provided one. I don't understand why your comment is still being upvoted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it does on my side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I don't understand where the issue lies, and how I am supposed to fix it.

Comment: @SAQ You have a constant array const char Name[STUDENT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] . So you may not change it.= "";

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I didn't even notice that. Thank you!

Comment: Please replace `char *` with `std::string`.  Always use `std::string`, unless you know otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Major Major = Major::Undefined;` does not compile for me:

> error: declaration of ‘Major Student::Major’ changes meaning of ‘Major’

After fixing that (by renaming either the `Major` enum or the `Student::Major` member), I then get the error about the deleted `operator=`, and the compiler also explains WHY it is deleted:

> note: ‘Student& Student::operator=(const Student&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed.
>
> error: non-static const member ‘const char Student::Name [5]’, cannot use default assignment operator

You have the `Student::Name` declared as an array of `const` characters. You can't write to `const` data, which is why the default `operator=` gets deleted by the compiler.

You need to remove the `const` from the `Student::Name` member:

```
struct Student {
    /*const*/ char Name[STUDENT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH] = "";
    ...
};
```

Comment: May I ask you what IDE are you using, as I don't see the explanation on VS?

Comment: @SAQ I used https://www.onlinegdb.com, which uses gcc/g++, and had it set to C++17.

Comment: @SAQ you are likely looking at the Error List. The Error list is an executive summary of the problems detected in the code, and as a summary, it leaves stuff out. If you change to the Output tab, you get the full build output and should see something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/7oaTbajne

Comment: @user4581301 the OP is using Visual Studio. Your example is using gcc. If you switch your example to use msvc, it does say the reason: "*note: 'Student &Student::operator =(const Student &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'Student' has a data member 'Student::Name' of const-qualified non-class type*"

Comment: I just noticed that. A screw-up on my part. I had MSVS selected, but must have gooned the selection before grabbing the link.

Comment: Side note: Compiler Explorer, the site I linked to, is really handy for stuff like this because you can tell it to show you the results in a variety of compilers. I find that if I get stuck, one of the other of the big three compilers will give me a diagnostic that I can understand: https://godbolt.org/z/78rzxjPM9 . On the far right you'll see the full MSVS output I was trying to show earlier.